# Data source block for google managed service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to use the data block of Google-managed service account(service-XXXXXX@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com) but **couldn't find the data block in the terraform registry** except the default compute service account. Can someone help me with this?

```
data "google_compute_default_service_account" "default" {
}

output "default_account" {
  value = data.google_compute_default_service_account.default.email
}
```

Reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_default_service_account

Output is: XXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Answer (score 1):

Google-provided service accounts, such as those used for Google Cloud services like Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, or App Engine, cannot be directly created or managed using Terraform. These service accounts are automatically provided by Google Cloud when you create and configure these services.

However, you can use Terraform to interact with and manage the roles and permissions associated with these service accounts within your GCP project. To do this, you would typically use the google_project_iam_binding resource to grant roles to these service accounts.

Here's an example of how to do that:

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "compute_engine" {
  project = "your-project-id"  # Replace with your GCP project ID
  role    = "roles/editor"    # Replace with the desired role
  members = ["serviceAccount:service-${google_project.compute_engine.project_number}@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com"]
}
```

To add the same IAM binding in gcp organization

```
resource "google_organization_iam_binding" "compute_engine" {
  org_id  = "your-organization-id"  # Replace with your GCP organization ID
  role    = "roles/editor"          # Replace with the desired role
  members = ["serviceAccount:service-${google_project.compute_engine.project_number}@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com"]
}
```

Comment: Raul did not ask about creation though. Furthermore, the string concatenation will only work if the Compute Engine API was activated with enough time in between, otherwise the service agent will not exist yet.